# Interface between a 'model' and 'view'

Tags: java, model-view-controller, interface, observer-pattern

A program has a view and a model (using the term loosely) in which the view is observing the model. The model has a handful of states, and the view has a handful of jpanels that are mapped onto the states (some states have several corresponding jpanels apiece). Using a cardlayout, one jpanel displays at a time, and a state change or change within a state will swap out the current jpanel for another. The pr[ogra](https://sourceforge.net/projects/somelameapp/)m works, but it seems like bad practice for the view and model to assume that there are exactly 5 states and 7 views. How may this be implemented.

```
class Model implements Observable {
  State A, B, C;
  final int VIEW_A = 0, VIEW_B = 1, VIEW_C0 = 2, VIEW_C1 = 3; 
  int stateView;
```

//argument will be one of the final ints above
  void setStateView(int stateView) { 
    this.stateView = stateView;
    notifyObservers();
  }

void getStateView() { return stateView; }
}

class View implements Observer {
  void update(Observable o) {
    //will use one of the ints above to identify the correct jPanel to display
    setJPanel ( o.getStateView() ); 
  }
}

I recognize the code above is an awful way of going about this. That's why I'm here. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. In using your `model` to maintain state, you are using the MVC design pattern correctly.
2. Assuming there are only 5 states is certainly ok *if there are only 5 states*. I do disagree with another practice you are using. Instead of using a bunch of `final int` declarations, I would define a `enum` that represents your state. I think that this could be a major reason why you think your program is ugly. It is, in my opinion, and your decision to not use `enum` is the reason.
3. This design is not very extensible. What if you eventually need 147 states? This is something to think about. One option is to use something besides a single integer as your state descriptor. Since I don't know what you're designing, it's hard for me to give good suggestions on this point.

Edit: to address another answer posted suggesting use of the Mediator pattern: I think this is overkill for this simple of an application. Your model is straightfoward, and your maintenance of states is not overly complex. Design is important, but going overkill on your design can lead to pitfalls as well.

Good luck,

-tjw

Comment: I am using the state pattern with a state interface that has enter(), exit(), execute(), nextState(), reset() methods. Is that good for this type of program? Thanks for the input, much appreciated.

Comment: Again, I don't know enough about the high-level design requirements of your application to tell you what the best choice is. The best indicator for the success of this particular application is the fact that you are *thinking* about the design, asking questions, and utilizing existing, battle-tested design patterns. While there always is a *best* way to do something, this *best* way is almost never known at the time the decision has to be made. It seems you are going about things in a sane, logical manner; I wrote the concerns that I have in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a class in the middle with the sole responsibility of mapping state to view. Have this class react to state changes by telling the view which panel to show. This keeps the mapping logic in a single place - the model knows nothing about views, and the view knows nothing about states. This is a variant of the [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern.